# Laravel's Cache::forever() - reliable?

Tags: php, caching, laravel, laravel-4

I'm wondering: how reliable is Laravel's Cache::forever() method?

Lately I had several ideas how I can use it to well... persist data that is generated during runtime. Can I rely on forever()? Will it really store values "forever" (well not stricly spoken forever since "forever" is 9999999999 minutes but well, that's long enough :-) ) as long as "artisan cache:clear" isn't executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, Laravel's caching mechanism is well tested. Just make sure that whatever database driver you have configured Laravel to use is set up properly. If it is caching your shorter queries as expected (5 minutes or so) then your `forever()` queries should be too.